# Use a part of the service name(version)

Tags: powershell, service, version

I am trying to copy files from folder `C:\example` to `D:\example\$version\` and I am trying to get `$version` from the display name of an installed service.

I think I need to do something like this, but I don't know how to get only the version of myservice:

```
$version = Get-Service -DisplayName "myservice *"
copy-item "c:\example\*" "d:\example\$version\" -recurse
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the version within the service name?

Comment: for example 5.0

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally down to how PowerShell returns data with a "get" command.   Remember that a "get-service" isn't just returning a string with your service name, but an "object" of collected data about the service.

```
PS C:\storage\scripts> get-service -DisplayName "Windows Search"

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  WSearch            Windows Search
```

This alone should show you that your $version variable is more than just the name of the service. What you need is to actually use the DisplayName component of the returned object:

```
PS C:\storage\scripts> $version = get-service -DisplayName "Windows Search"
PS C:\storage\scripts> $version.DisplayName
Windows Search
```

Hopefully this should get you on your way.

EDIT: As far as the actual service version goes, get-service doesn't extend to that level, but one can use a .NET call to get this from an executable file:

```
PS C:\Program Files\7-Zip> [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe").FileVersion 
16.04
```

Comment: Ok great thanks.
that will help.

I got only one more question how do I use the version part only for example If windows search has an version in the display name like :
Windows Search 5.0 and I only want to use the version 5.0

Thanks again

Comment: I've just edited my original answer to help with that. In short, get-service doesn't offer that sadly. You'll have to track down the executable it points to and use that for versioning.

Comment: @michieln see the other answer, I think it does what you're requesting.

Comment: @michieln you might also look in to the wmi syntax: `PS C:\Program Files\7-Zip> (gwmi win32_service|?{$_.name -eq "nsi"}).pathname`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your service name has the version number at the end of it's name and that it is separated from the rest of the name by a space character you could do this:

```
$ServiceName = (Get-Service -displayname "myservice *" | Select -Last 1).DisplayName
$Version = ($ServiceName -Split ' ')[-1]

copy-item "c:\example\*" "d:\example\$Version\" -recurse
```

**Explanation:**

- Gets the service by wildcard pattern (as you provided) and then uses `Select -Last 1` in case there are multiple matches so that it gets the last (should be highest version) alphabetically.
- Uses the `-split` operator to split the displayname into an array of strings on the space character and then gets the last item in the resultant array via the index identifier `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete example which uses the `-replace` function instead of a *split*:

```
$serviceName = 'myservice'
$version = (Get-Service -DisplayName "$serviceName*").DisplayName -replace "$serviceName\s*(.*)", '$1'
Copy-Item "c:\example\*" "d:\example\$version\" -recurse
```